# Unable to start debugging. Unexpected gdb output from command "-environment-cd" "Path" No such file or directory

Tags: c++, visual-c++

When I set default C++ compiler to g++ and run the code I received [This error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhAJm.png), this is my launch.json

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "C/C++: g++.exe build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\msys64\\ucrt64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                    "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file"
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

and this is my task.json(if any adjustment is necessary):

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\ucrt64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build"
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        },
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\ucrt64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Before I made this post, none of the solutions/videos I found online and in stackoverflow worked for me, I'd like to know  where I went wrong, possible solutions, or different ways to compile my C++ file automatically when it's ran (as I dont want to compile it manually every time I run it)

Comment: My guess would be that the non-ascii characters in your path are not being handled correctly by the linker

Comment: I tried UTF+8 for worldwide language but that doesn't solve the problem either

Comment: Just use ascii paths, it'll be much more reliable

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I had to move my house, thanks for the suggestion, it worked.